# Converting the formatted date to string in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to convert the date format yyyy-MM-dd to yyyy/MM/dd in from XML

```
<requestMessage>
    <custRefNo>123456789876</custRefNo>
    <printDate>2017-09-09</printDate>
    <dbName>default</dbName>
    <filename>abcedfed</filename>
    <filePointer>ABCDEFGHIJKL</filePointer>
    <format>afp</format>
</requestMessage>
```

using the XSL tranfomration

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/requestMessage">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ouaf.oracle.com/">
            <soapenv:Header/>

            <soapenv:Body>
                <ws:documentInfo>
                    <ws:dbname>
                        <xsl:value-of select="dbName"/>
                    </ws:dbname>
                    <ws:account>
                        <xsl:value-of select="custRefNo"/>
                    </ws:account>
                    <ws:date>
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-date(printDate,'[Y0001]/[M01]/[D01]')"/>
                    </ws:date>
                    <ws:format>
                        <xsl:value-of select="format"/>
                    </ws:format>
                    <ws:file>
                        <xsl:value-of select="filename"/>
                    </ws:file>
                    <ws:pointer>
                        <xsl:value-of select="filePointer"/>
                    </ws:pointer>

                </ws:documentInfo>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and getting the XML

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ws="http://ouaf.oracle.com/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ws:documentInfo>
            <ws:dbname>default</ws:dbname>
            <ws:account>123456789876</ws:account>
            <ws:date>2017/09/09</ws:date>
            <ws:format>afp</ws:format>
            <ws:file>abcedfed</ws:file>
            <ws:pointer>ABCDEFGHIJKL</ws:pointer>
        </ws:documentInfo>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But i think my XSL is changing the node from string to Date format. And due to it my web service is failing. Can anybody suggest how to convert the formatted date in string again using my XSL.

Comment: What kind of failure do you get exactly?

Comment: I am getting the Null Pointer exception while transforming while i am passing all the values.

Comment: What makes you think it is the date node that is causing a problem? What happens if you try doing `translate(printDate, '-', '/')` instead of using `format-date`?

Comment: I agree with @TimC I don't see any reason why ws:date would be a date instead of a string. What makes you think that it is failing because it is a date ? Maybe you should add the stacktrace of your webservice so that we can see what is the error that happens.

Comment: If you get a NullPointerException we definitely need to see the stack trace.

Comment: Maybe you should try to convert the date like this: <xsl:value-of select="format-date(xs:date(printDate),'[Y0001]/[M01]/[D01]')"/>

Comment: Thank you all the issue is resolved now. The problem was in the target XSD format which is given as string. That is why it wasn't accepting the     
            format-date(printDate,'[Y0001]/[M01]/[D01]'). Now i am using the  translate(printDate, '-', '/') to format my Date.